# java binary search tree delete two children

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I wrote the code for the two cases where you have to find the successor then move it up. It seems to work but when I print out the tree it makes two of children. For example my tree is

```
        /
       18
      /  \
     17  19
```

That's just part of my tree that I'm working on, when I try to delete 18 it deletes it but then when I print out the tree the printout is 17 17 19 19. Below is my code:

```
System.out.println("what is t " + T.getData()); 
System.out.println("what is t's right " + T.getRight().getData());
System.out.println("what is t's left " + T.getLeft().getData());
sucessor = findSucessor(T);
System.out.println("2 what is sucessor " + sucessor.getData());

T.getRight().setLeft(sucessor.getRight());
sucessor.setLeft(T.getLeft());
T.setData(sucessor.getData());
```

My successor goes one to the right and all the way left as long as its not null so in this case the successor is 19.

I think its just the pointers that are confusing me, I'm not cutting off the links but I cant figure out where.

Comment: Why don't you follow the alternative method of deleting a node in a search tree by using a special value (e.g. boolean) to "mark" that this node is deleted (without physically deleting it). This means next time you try to search for the value in that node, it won't find it because it is marked as deleted.

Comment: What is `T`? Also [don't use variables that start with uppercase](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Comment: T is the node that contains the number that is to be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like that instead:

```
successor.getParent().replace(successor, successor.getRight());
successor.setLeft(T.getLeft());
successor.setRight(T.getRight();
T.getParent().replace(T, successor);
```